# 16.04: Repository is no longer signed

Tags: repository

Ran `sudo apt update` on 16.04 and see this error:

> E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release' is no longer signed.

This a problem on my end, or is there maintenance needed on the repository servers, and I just need to be patient?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue is only with the repository at http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb which appears to be for Google Earth.  Went to the Software Updater, unchecked this repository under Settings->Other Software, ran the update and all is well; except Google Earth may never again be updated.